# Generar acción con select y button html,javascript

Tags: javascript, html, html5

Buen día tengo el siguiente menú desplegable

```
 <select class="form-control" name="seleccion" id="seleccion">
    <option value="0">Seleccione el tipo de certificado</option>
    <option value="1">Carta Laboral Estandar</option>
    <option value="2">Carta Laboral Sin Salario</option>
    <option value="3">Ingresos y Retenciones 2017</option>
  </select>
  <br>
  <input type="button" name="generar" value="Imprimir" class="btn btn-success btn-lg" onclick="carta();">
```

lo que deseo es que mediante la función onclick="carta(); al presionar el botón ,puede ejecutar una instruccion dependiendo la seleccion

```
    function carta(){
 si se esta seleccionado  value=1 -> haga
 si se esta seleccionado  value=2 -> haga
 si se esta seleccionado  value=3 -> haga

}
```

como podría hacerlo Gracias

Answer (score 5):

Puedes acceder a la propiedad `value` del `select`. Con ello tendrás el `value` de la `option` seleccionada.

```js
function carta(){
  let selectedValue = document.getElementById("seleccion").value;
  console.log(selectedValue);
}
```

```html
<select class="form-control" name="seleccion" id="seleccion">
    <option value="0">Seleccione el tipo de certificado</option>
    <option value="1">Carta Laboral Estandar</option>
    <option value="2">Carta Laboral Sin Salario</option>
    <option value="3">Ingresos y Retenciones 2017</option>
  </select>
  <br>
  <input type="button" name="generar" value="Imprimir" class="btn btn-success btn-lg" onclick="carta();">
```

Comment: Gracias asi era lo que necesitaba

Comment: Si te ha servido pon la respuesta como aceptada. Debajo de la puntuación de la respuesta, a la izquierda de donde empieza, aparece un tick, una especie de v, haz click y se pondrá en ver. Tu ganarás dos puntos de reputación, kiko 15 y los demás sabremos que esta solución funciona si nos vemos en tu mismo problema. Un saludo.

Answer (score 0):

Lo que tienes que hacer es obtener el `value` de la `option`, y después realizar las comparaciones con los `if`.

```js
var e = document.getElementById("seleccion");

function carta(){
  let optionValue = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
  if(optionValue == 1){
    alert(optionValue)
  }
  if(optionValue == 2){
    alert(optionValue)
  }
  if(optionValue == 3){
    alert(optionValue)
  }
}
```

```html
<select class="form-control" name="seleccion" id="seleccion">
    <option value="0">Seleccione el tipo de certificado</option>
    <option value="1">Carta Laboral Estandar</option>
    <option value="2">Carta Laboral Sin Salario</option>
    <option value="3">Ingresos y Retenciones 2017</option>
 </select>
 <br>
 <input type="button" name="generar" value="Imprimir" class="btn btn-success btn-lg" onclick="carta();">
```

Saludos.